# Getting error "invalid value encountered in double_scalars" in simple function

Tags: python, function, math

I'm relatively new to python and I've been trying to do some of my university work on it to get used to the language. I came up with this problem and I saw some other people also asked about it, but it does not seem applicable to my case. Here is the code:

```
from numpy import *
from scipy.optimize import *
import math
def f(z):
    Q1 = z[0]
    Q2 = z[1]
    
    Qdim = 25000*1.3*1000/(24*60*60)
    L1 = 2700
    L2 = 3300
    D1 = 800/1000
    D2 = 600/1000
    A1 = math.pi*(D1**2)/4
    A2 = math.pi*(D2**2)/4
    V1 = Q1/A1
    V2 = Q2/A2
    v = 497*10**-6/(52.5**1.5)
    Re1 = ((Q1/A1)*D1)/v
    Re2 = ((Q2/A2)*D2)/v
    k = 0.4
    f1 = 0.25/((math.log10(5.1286/Re1**0.89+k/(3.7*D1*1000)))**2)
    f2 = 0.25/((math.log10(5.1286/Re2**0.89+k/(3.7*D2*1000)))**2)
    
    
    F = empty((2))
    F[0] = Q1 + Q2 - Qdim
    F[1] = f1*L1/D1 * (V1**2) - f2*L2/D2 * (V2**2)
    
    return F
zGuess = array([1,1])
z = fsolve(f,zGuess)
```

When I run that, I immediately get the error:

```
D:\Tudo\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:19: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars
```

As soon as I remove "f2" from F[1], I get some values, but far from what I expected. In other questions, the problem was that the output was too small, so other libraries had to be used. I don't believe this is the case here, as I'm not working with numbers to the power of -100.

Comment: Well an invalid number occurs if for instance you are trying to calculate the log of a negative number as the log function is not defined for negative numbers.

Comment: I modified your code by printing the argument of the log function before and in some iterations you are handing `nan` values to it.. that's likely what is causing your error

Comment: Hmm that makes sense.